# dectect video with yolov4-tiny

Tags: python, yolo

so I trained a yolov4 tiny model and I predict perfectly on images with this command :

```
!./darknet detect build/darknet/x64/cfg/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector.cfg build/darknet/x64/backup/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_final.weights build/darknet/x64/data/obj/0b6093ce1fce5b8f.jpg -dont-show
```

and now I want to predict on video but I can manage to figure out the correct command.

Comment: This [link](https://medium.com/@riteshkanjee/how-to-run-yolov4-on-images-and-video-70428e916070) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run detections on a video file run `detector demo`. In your case:

`!.darknet detector demo build/darknet/x64/cfg/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector.cfg build/darknet/x64/backup/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_final.weights -ext_output build/darknet/x64/data/obj/your_video.mp4 -dont_show`

If you want to see the predictions on the video, add `-out_filename your_video.mp4`

So the command becomes:

`!.darknet detector demo build/darknet/x64/cfg/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector.cfg build/darknet/x64/backup/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_final.weights -ext_output build/darknet/x64/data/obj/your_video.mp4 -out_filename detection_results_your_video.mp4 -dont_show`